# How to use PHPexcel to replace tags in excel template?

Tags: templates, replace, phpexcel

I was defined some tags in the excel template, but I don't know how to use PHPexcel to replace those tags in the template?

require_once './Classes/PHPExcel.php';

```
$filepath = './tpl.xlsx'; 
$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($filepath);  
$sheetData = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet(0)->toArray();      


$PHPExcel = new PHPExcel(); 


$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($sheetData, 'Excel5'); 


$filename = time().'.xlsx';
$objWriter->save('./'.$filename);
```

Comment: If you could explain what you meant by tags.... otherwise I don't really understand what you're trying to do

Comment: These tags are used to replace the real data!

Comment: If those tags are in cells, then you need to loop through the cells reading the values, checking for tags in that value, and replacing where necessary and resetting the cell value

Comment: Thanks in advance, but I don't how to operate?

Comment: haha, thanks! I know how to solve